# Pending Intent in Notification not working Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

My pending intent not working as to be expected to work.

**Issue is:** When tapping on Notification it redirects to Splash Activity that is my launcher Activity of application, following is my code for creating notification.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuickTasks.class).putExtra("NOTIFICATION", 1);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Suvi")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
```

Please help me in this regard i have used many of resources available here, but none of worked. Any help could be appreciable.

Comment: what you mean by `pending intent not working as to be expected to work`? explain the behavior along with excepted behavior

Comment: I want to open QuickTasks.class rather opening Splash Screen

Comment: are you sure that somehow `QuickTasks.class` is not related to splash activity, try it without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and if you are still unable to see `QuickTasks.class` then there's a logical issue is in your code

Comment: Does your QuickTask have a special behavior on his start ? Who may automaticly redirects you to your splash activity ?

Comment: Splash Activity is my laucher main Activity

Comment: post your manifest please.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you want to **start an activity from a notification**, there is **two** cases:

1. **Regular** Activity:
   You're starting an Activity that's part of the application's normal workflow.
2. **Special** Activity:
   The user only sees this Activity if it's started from a notification. In a sense, the Activity extends the notification by providing information that would be hard to display in the notification itself.

Please refer to the following link.

[Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/notify-user/navigation.html#ExtendedNotification)

I hope this helps you.